# Who has the power to delete comments?

Tags: support, comments, moderators

Today I commented to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720292/44126) because it had "particle" in the tags, which I edited out and left a comment to that effect. Of course the revised final does not have "particle" in the tags, and the comment becomes irrelevant, BUT, please remember that there are older physicists answering and commenting , who continually have to check if they should still be doing so. Disappearing comments do not help in this. Please leave a comment for the writer to delete the useless comment, instead of just tidying up.

Answer (score 12):

The diamond moderators can delete comments.  Comments which meet certain criteria may disappear after flagging by certain non-moderator users without further intervention; I don't know where those criteria are documented, but I've seen it happen.

That particular question is a little weird because it was [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720267/44126) [twice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720292/44126).  You edited one of them, and then commented about your edit on the other one.  This kind of confusing strangeness is a good reason for fixing closed questions rather than re-asking them.

> Please leave a comment for the writer to delete the useless comment, instead of just tidying up.

I don't expect us to start doing this for comments which are clearly obsolete, because it means the moderators would have to touch every such post at least twice: once to identify an obsolete comment, then sometime later to check whether the obsolete comment had been removed by its author.